# Can i use a Marionette behavior multiple times on a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I woud like to have an itemView with for example to InputFileBehaviors on 2 different elements.
Like

```
View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   behaviors:{
     InputFile : {
       elementSelector : "input.file1",
      field : "file1"
    },
   InputFile : {
     elementSelector : "input.file2",
     field : "file2"
  }
}
```

Obviously this can't work because you will overwrite the key in the associative array, but is there another way to add  a behavior multiple times to the same view, and if not give me an alternative strategy?

Update:
Ok I found the solution.
If you use behaviorClass and different keyNames you can get the desired functionality, only issue might be that you can't do behavior lookups anymore on the behavior you are reusing.
Example if anyone else gets the same problem:

```
View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   behaviors:{
     InputFile1 : {
      behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
       elementSelector : "input.file1",
      field : "file1"
    },
   InputFile2 : {
     behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
     elementSelector : "input.file2",
     field : "file2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note as of 2.4.1 you can pass in an array:

```
View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  behaviors: [
    {
      behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
      elementSelector : "input.file1",
      field : "file1"
    }, {
      behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
      elementSelector : "input.file2",
      field : "file2"
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ok I found the solution. If you use behaviorClass and different keyNames you can get the desired functionality, only issue might be that you can't do behavior lookups anymore on the behavior you are reusing. Example if anyone else gets the same problem:

```
View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  behaviors:{
    InputFile1 : {
      behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
      elementSelector : "input.file1",
      field : "file1"
    },
    InputFile2 : {
      behaviorClass : MyApp.Behaviors.InputFile1,
      elementSelector : "input.file2",
      field : "file2"
    }
```

}

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, the principle of marionette.behaviors is to respect the DRY principle. and it seems your solution does repeat itself.

Comment: If your behavior can receive an array of objects with selector and field properties, then the behavior implementation will loop on each object in the array that is provided...